# In swift I'm passing 2 Strings between View Controllers, how can I separate them to use them in different functions?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I'm passing 2 separate strings from VC1 to VC2 with no issues, the question I have is, how can I separate them in VC2 to use each string in different functions. Here is my code:

**VC1**

```
 let nextVC = VC2()
 nextVC.info = ((String(indexPath.section), viewModel.value!))
 navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

**VC2**

```
 var info = ("", "")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The two strings are `info.0` and `info.1`.

Still, this seems a very silly way to pass the information. Why not have two properties, an Int and an Optional String? That is what your original data are. The key to good programming is to say what you mean, and not some other thing.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your comment, I’m still learning. How can I pass the original data (Int, String) to VC2 and keep them separate? Instead of info.0 and info.1